# How to insert deserialized xml components into sql table?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert certain parts of an xml document into a sql table. I have so far deserialized the xml into objects and can display them on console but can't insert them into a sql server table. 
As a note the table I am trying to make needs to have 1 row only(at this stage at least), and has several columns. Also, the xml file I am working with is an invoice.

This is what  I tried so far:

```
public static void InsertEntries(IEnumerable<UBLGelen> entries)
    {

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WIZM - W10 - P347ZC;Initial Catalog= WIZM - W10 - P347ZC;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                const string Text = "INSERT INTO Entries (ProfileID, ID, UUID, IssueDate, SenderName, VKN, VKNCustomer) VALUES (@ProfileID{0},@ID{0},@UUID{0},@IssueDate{0},@SenderName{0}, @VKN{0},@VKNCustomer{0} );";
                int count = 0;
                string query = string.Empty;

                foreach (var data in entries)
                {

                    query += string.Format(Text, count);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@ProfileID {0}", count), data.ProfileID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@ID {0}", count), data.ID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@UUID {0}", count), data.UUID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@IssueDate {0}", count), data.IssueDate);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@SenderName {0}", count), data.AccountingSupplierParty.Party.PartyName.FirstOrDefault().Name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@VKN {0}", count), data.AccountingSupplierParty.Party.PartyIdentification.FirstOrDefault().ID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@VKNCustomer {0}", count), data.AccountingCustomerParty.Party.PartyIdentification.FirstOrDefault().ID);
                    count++;
                }
                cmd.CommandText = query;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove spaces from parameter statements  -> should be "@ProfileID{0}" instead of "@ProfileID {0}". It's also not clear why you create all those inside one command. Independend commands would have more expected behavior

Comment: You need to flatten the deserialized classes into a table of rows and columns.  Without seeing the xml I do not know the best method for doing the flattening.  I usually do not use the xml serialize method in these cases because it creates a lot a layers of classes.  Instead I parse Xml using XDocument (linq) which I'm able to flatten to a table format and make it easier to store into the database.

Comment: Why did you remove the formatting @Larnu?

Comment: I didn't, @kara, that's what your edit did, and hence why i rolled it back (as per my comment in my rollback). Adding `c#` to the start caused the parser to not be able to work out what language it was. Also having 4 white spaces and 3 backticks at the start both work for making the code show in a code block. :) As a result your edit just made the colouring disappear; making the code harder to read, not easier.

Comment: Rel: don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8) after the cmd.CommandText = query line, as can be seen bellow:

```
public static void InsertEntries(IEnumerable<UBLGelen> entries)
{

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WIZM - W10 - P347ZC;Initial Catalog= WIZM - W10 - P347ZC;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            const string Text = "INSERT INTO Entries (ProfileID, ID, UUID, IssueDate, SenderName, VKN, VKNCustomer) VALUES (@ProfileID{0},@ID{0},@UUID{0},@IssueDate{0},@SenderName{0}, @VKN{0},@VKNCustomer{0} );";
            int count = 0;
            string query = string.Empty;

            foreach (var data in entries)
            {

                query += string.Format(Text, count);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@ProfileID {0}", count), data.ProfileID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@ID {0}", count), data.ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@UUID {0}", count), data.UUID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@IssueDate {0}", count), data.IssueDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@SenderName {0}", count), data.AccountingSupplierParty.Party.PartyName.FirstOrDefault().Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@VKN {0}", count), data.AccountingSupplierParty.Party.PartyIdentification.FirstOrDefault().ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@VKNCustomer {0}", count), data.AccountingCustomerParty.Party.PartyIdentification.FirstOrDefault().ID);
                count++;
            }
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I tried it but has not solved the issue, my table still seems to be empty.

Comment: As @MikkaRin say, remove empty space in all AddWithValue calls, exp. 
    string.Format("@ProfileID {0}", count) ->     string.Format("@ProfileID{0}", count), to correspond parameters in text variable , @ProfileID{0},@ID{0},@UUID{0}...

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there you just you need to add the SQL Connection to the command

```
public static void InsertEntries(IEnumerable<UBLGelen> entries)
        {

            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WIZM - W10 - P347ZC;Initial Catalog= WIZM - W10 - P347ZC;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    const string Text = "INSERT INTO Entries (ProfileID, ID, UUID, IssueDate, SenderName, VKN, VKNCustomer) VALUES (@ProfileID{0},@ID{0},@UUID{0},@IssueDate{0},@SenderName{0}, @VKN{0},@VKNCustomer{0} );";
                    int count = 0;
                    string query = string.Empty;

                    foreach (var data in entries)
                    {

                        query += string.Format(Text, count);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@ProfileID {0}", count), data.ProfileID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@ID {0}", count), data.ID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@UUID {0}", count), data.UUID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@IssueDate {0}", count), data.IssueDate);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@SenderName {0}", count), data.AccountingSupplierParty.Party.PartyName.FirstOrDefault().Name);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@VKN {0}", count), data.AccountingSupplierParty.Party.PartyIdentification.FirstOrDefault().ID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@VKNCustomer {0}", count), data.AccountingCustomerParty.Party.PartyIdentification.FirstOrDefault().ID);
                        count++;
                    }
                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```